# Regex to remove special characters(Latin 1)

Tags: java, regex

I have trouble in removing following special chacters:

input:

> Curiosity Finds â€œSurprisingâ€ Amounts of Water, Perchlorate On Mars

desired output:

> Curiosity Finds "Surprising" Amounts of Water, Perchlorate On Mars

just need to convert â€œ into ".

Thanks in Advance
Rohit

Comment: Where the input come from? Seems more an encoding problem then something else.

Comment: Try to URLEncode.encode(your_string, "UTF-8") before you send it. When you receive it you can decode it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is to remove all non-ASCII letter like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\u007f]+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the exact thing you're asking for:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "Curiosity Finds â€œSurprisingâ€ Amounts of Water, Perchlorate On Mars";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\u00E2\\u20AC\\u0153?", "\"");
        System.out.println("str="+str);
    }
}
```

Output:

> str=Curiosity Finds "Surprising" Amounts of Water, Perchlorate On Mars

You can try it out here:  http://ideone.com/WHCXUj

And for future reference, a handy online unicode character lookup is here: http://unicodelookup.com

Here's how I used it, for instance:  http://unicodelookup.com/#â€œ/1